# StableBaselines3 - How to create callback on env.reset()

Tags: python, callback, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am training an agent on a custom environment using the PPO implementation from `stable_baselines3`. Is there a way to create a custom callback that is executed after every reset of the environment during training?

There are a couple of custom event callbacks listed in the docs, but none of them take effect after an environment reset:
https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/callbacks.html